# How do I run a CGI script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cgi

I am trying to run a simple program of python when values are sent from html page.

The html file is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Minimum Bootstrap HTML Skeleton</title>

    <!--  -->

    <style>

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

    <form action="search.py" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="x_name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And here is my search.py file

```
import cgi
import cgitb

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
name = form.getvalue('x_name')


print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Now, when I run the html file and enter name field and submit it, instead of processing the search.py file, it just displays the code written in search.py
Like this:
[Check the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A2UH.png)

Any help regarding how to proceed further to run the files would be helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Have you configured Apache to treat Python files as CGI? Show the config.

Comment: No, How do I do that?